# How to bypass web session key when I request device API

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a web application and a ios application(wasn't made by me, I can't do any code changes there), but both of them are using same backend in order to get data(this is the part where I have access) backend part if written in php on codeigniter framework. 
When I did login part on the website I used a login controller and a hook to pass the session on all my controllers.

this is the login side:

```
public function login_validation() {
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','Username',
        'required|trim|callback_validate_credentials');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','required|trim');

    if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
        $data= array(
            'username'=> $this->input->post('username'),
            'is_logged_in' => true
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata($data);
        redirect('Monitor');
    } else {
        $this->load->view('login');
    }
}
```

and this is my hook:

```
<?php
class Authenticate {
    protected $CI;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->CI = &get_instance();
    }

    public function check_user_login() {
        $isLoginRequested = $this->_endsWith(base_url(uri_string()), "Main/login");
        $isLoginValidating = $this->_endsWith(base_url(uri_string()), "Main/login_validation");

        // echo  $this->CI->session->userdata('is_logged_in') ;
        if(false == $this->CI->session->userdata('is_logged_in') && 
              $isLoginRequested == false && $isLoginValidating == false) {
            redirect('Main/login');    
        }
    }

    function _endsWith($haystack, $needle) {
        $length = strlen($needle);
        if ($length == 0) {
            return true;
        }
        return (substr($haystack, -$length) === $needle);
    }
}
?>
```

Now the login on the ios device is requesting header X-SESSION-KEY on the api. On this api :

```
public function types() {
    $userSession = $this->_get_user_session();
    $reqLanguage = $this->input->get_request_header('Accept-Language');

    if ($userSession != null) {
        if ($userSession->isLoggedIn() == true) {
            $this->_issue_success($this->ptypes->getAll($reqLanguage));
        } else {
            $this->_issue_respond_with_reason("The provided session is invalid.", HttpResponse::Forbidden);
        }
    } else {
        $this->_issue_respond_with_reason("No session key supplied.", HttpResponse::Forbidden);
    }
```

But what is happening now, on the same URL(like I told both applications are using same backend) my ios app is requesting now the web session not the API side, and I will get redirected on the login.
And on that URL(on the ios app) I get:

```
{"reason":"No session key supplied."}
```

and my controllers aren't sending any data. 
My question is that, how I can make a if variable on the login controller side, when the user (logged from ios) is requesting the API sessions side, bypass my web session session and avoid that no session key supplied. 
Before my login, the application was working fine.